# No AndroidManifest.xml file in my Unity project

Tags: unity-game-engine, android-manifest, google-play-console

I can't find the AndroidManifest.xml file.
I am working on a Unity project and uploading the app to google play console.

I searched in the places:

- *Assets\Plugins\Android* -> The "Plugins" folder does not exist.
- *Temp\StagingArea* -> The "StagingArea" folder does not exist.
- *C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.26f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Apk* -> the existing files are: "LauncherManifest.xml" and "UnityManifest.xml".

I found the AndroidManifest.xml file in the places **:**

- *C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.26f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK\sources\third_party\vulkan\src\build-android\cmake\layerlib\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml*
- *C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.26f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK\sources\third_party\vulkan\src\build-android\AndroidManifest.xml*

But I think these are not the correct files that needed.

What can i do?
Thanks for the advices and the answers.

Answer (score 4):

Into Unity 3d do to Player Settings -> Player -> Publishing Settings -> Build-> Custom Main Manifest (check). Now go in Project Assets\Plugins\Android\AndroidManifest.xml.